# Sinon.JS mocking confusion

Tags: jquery, mocking, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I'm trying to learn how to do JS unit testing using Sinon, Mocha, and Chai. Right now, I want to confirm that one of my functions actually makes an api request (so I need to mock my function). I believe that I've found relevant mocking code in the Sinon docs (it's code for testing Ajax), however, I can't make any sense of what's going on (the documentation is very sparse). Can anyone explain each of the 3 lines of code in the it function (directly below)?

```
it("makes a GET request for todo items", function () {
  sinon.replace(jQuery, "ajax", sinon.fake());

  getTodos(42, sinon.fake());

  assert(jQuery.ajax.calledWithMatch({ url: "/todo/42/items" }));
```

For reference, the function being mocked is directly below:

```
function getTodos(listId, callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/todo/" + listId + "/items",
    success: function (data) {
      // Node-style CPS: callback(err, data)
      callback(null, data);
    },
  });
}
```

Also, here is a link to the documentation:
https://sinonjs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go step by step:

#### 1. sinon.replace(jQuery, "ajax", sinon.fake());

Sinon creates a new [fake](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.1/fakes/) function and replaces jQuery.ajax function with it.

Any other calls to `jQuery.ajax` will invoke the fake. By default, the fake function  returns `undefined`, you can control that as well; but it is not needed here(since we will assert if it's called with certain arguments or not). The fake function has the same methods as [spies](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.1/spies/), so a fake function will record information regarding its calls, like spies. (whether it is called, with which arguments etc.)

#### 2. getTodos(42, sinon.fake());

`getTodos` is the function that is tested. This calls it with 42 as first argument and a new fake function as second argument(callback argument).

Probably, a fake is passed to prevent side effects of using an actual callback. one can also put a empty function instead like

```js
getTodos(42, () => {});
```

The callback function does not matter for this test. It just needs to be discarded/mocked.

#### 3. assert(jQuery.ajax.calledWithMatch({ url: "/todo/42/items" }));

The assertion checks for the expression `jQuery.ajax.calledWithMatch({ url: "/todo/42/items" })` to be true. Remember, `jQuery.ajax` was replaced with a fake function. So, the fake function's `calledWithMatch` method is called. According to the docs of calledWithMatch(in spies section):

```
spy.calledWithMatch(arg1, arg2, ...);
Returns true if spy was called with matching arguments (and possibly others).

This behaves the same as spy.calledWith(sinon.match(arg1), sinon.match(arg2), ...).
```

so if the fake function is called with arguments(only one provided here) that are matching, it returns true. "Matching" behaviour is defined via [matchers](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.1/matchers/). Here object matcher is used(sinon.match(object)), which matches if

```
sinon.match(object);
Requires the value to be not null or undefined and have at least the same properties as expectation.

This supports nested matchers.
```

So, this object is passed to jQuery.ajax in getTodo:

```
{
    url: "/todo/42/items",
    success: function (data) {
      callback(null, data);
    },
}
```

which matches

```
{ url: "/todo/42/items" }
```

according to the object matcher definition. So, this matcher checks if jQuery.ajax method is called with an object that includes a url property with value `"/todo/42/items"`.

#### To sum up

1. First we mocked `jQuery.ajax` since we don't want to make actual requests, just want to check if it's called.
2. We call `getTodos`, which is our test subject, with 42 and a fake callback arguments.
3. We expect `jQuery.ajax` to be called with an object that has url property with value "/todo/42/items".